# Ist "siehe oben" in einem Buch sinnvoll?

Tags: word-usage, book

Ich schrieb "siehe oben" in meinem Buch (als ich auf eine frühere Stelle verwies), und der Verleger meinte, "oben"/"unten" gäbe es nur in Textdokumenten, aber nicht in Büchern (es sei denn, der verwiesene Sachverhalt kommt auf dergleichen Seite wie der Verweis selbst vor).

Meine Ansicht ist hingegen durch die Bedeutung 4 in https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/oben#Bedeutung4 und 1b in https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Buch gegeben.

Wer hat Recht?

Eine Anmerkung ist fällig (die aber nichts zur Sache tut). Ich weiß genau, wie das Buch formatiert wird: der Verleger bekommt nur eine PDF, sogar die Länge und Breite der Druckversion sind mir bekannt.

Comment: War das ein Verlag für Bilderbücher? Ansonsten ergibt die Phrase „_[...] nur in Textdokumenten, aber nicht in Büchern [...]_“ nämlich keinen Sinn.

Answer (score 5):

Meines Erachtens ist "siehe oben" eine so übliche Standard-Formulierung, dass man sie auch in Büchern verwenden *kann*, wenn man damit auf eine kurz zuvor erwähnte Sache hinweist.
Steht das, worauf man sich bezieht, auf derselben Seite, ist die Sache ohnehin klar, und ich wüsste auch gar keine Alternative.
Liegt die betreffende Stelle auf einer vorangegangen Seite, ist es vielleicht üblicher, "siehe Seite X" zu schreiben - das Problem eines derartigen Verweises ist jedoch, dass man ihn erst dann einfügen kann, wenn die endgültige Fassung fertig ist (und zwar sowohl inhaltlich als auch vom Layout her), sonst verschiebt sich der entsprechende Passus womöglich noch.
Beträgt der Abstand mehr als nur wenige Seiten, ist es allerdings besser, "siehe Kapitel Y" zu schreiben - gegebenenfalls mit Unterkapitel oder dann eben doch mit genauer Seitenzahl.

Comment: "Siehe Seite X" sollte in einem Buch nie verwendet werden, da wie angesprochen sich bis zur Drucklegung sehr viel verändern kann oder man denke an eine Zweitauflage in einem anderen Format. Bei eBooks ergibt dieser Ausdruck auch nicht immer Sinn, da diese teilweise gar keine Seitenzahlen mehr haben, bzw die Anzahl der Seiten sich mit der am Reader eingestellten Schriftgröße verändern kann. (Auch wenn man hier mit Sprungmarken Alternativen hat, die aber vorher eingefügt werden müssen.)

Comment: @mtwde: EIn Satzsystem oder auch eine nur mittelmäßige Textverarbeitung schafft das schon, wenn man einen ordentlichen Querverweis einbaut und nicht nur *36* schreibt.

Comment: @guidot Danke für den Hinweis. Da schlägt die moderne Technik die damals vermittelten Regeln :D . Hab sogar noch ein Buch eines Dozenten das verschenkt wurde, weil in der Auflage solche Fehler (und weitere) enthalten waren.

Answer (score 5):

"Siehe oben" findet man oft genug in Büchern, um ein "gibt es nicht" zu widerlegen.

Allerdings hat der Verleger meiner Meinung nach recht, wenn er "siehe oben" vermieden sehen möchte. "Siehe oben" kann sich auf den vorigen Absatz oder aber auch auf das andere Ende des Buches beziehen. Wenn auf Seite 478 mit "siehe oben" auf Seite 178 verwiesen wird, ignoriert der Leser entweder den Hinweis oder beginnt mit einer unerfreulichen Suche.

Falls - wie hier - die Angabe von Seitenzahlen keine Option ist, sollte man meiner Meinung nach zumindest Hinweise geben, die für eine schnelle Suche hilfreicher sind, zum Beispiel: "wie gerade eben ...", "siehe Kapitel X", "wie bereits im Zusammenhang mit ...".

Comment: "ignoriert der Leser entweder den Hinweis oder beginnt mit einer unerfreulichen Suche" - finde ich nicht. "Siehe oben" bewirkt ja nicht, dass der Leser reflexartig "oben" nachliest. Wäre das der Fall, wäre der Lesefluss ja unweigerlich unterbrochen. Vielmehr bewirkt es mMn, dass sich der Leser ins Gedächtnis ruft, dass ein Sachverhalt oder Begriff bereits weiter vorne erläutert wurde (und an dieser Stelle auch genauso gemeint ist), bevor der Leser sich über eine scheinbar fehlende Erklärung wundert und *dadurch* der Lesefluss unterbrochen wird.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Was Du meinst, war bei mir unter "ignoriert" inbegriffen, selbst wenn "siehe oben" in diesem Fall seine gewünschte Aufgabe erfüllt haben sollte.